# Como pegar o valor do el no Vue?

Tags: vue.js

Tenho a variável Vue:

```
var appExemplo = new Vue({
    el: "#appExemplo"
});
```

Como posso pegar o valor que está no `el`? Que neste exemplo seria `#appExemplo`.

`This.el` retorna indefinido.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

você quer obter o `DOM` manipulado pelo `vue`?

você pode usar a propriedade `$el`

```js
var appExemplo = new Vue({
  el: "#appExemplo",
    data: {
    message: 'Hello World!'
  }
});

console.log(appExemplo.$el.id, appExemplo.$el);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="appExemplo">
  {{ message }}
</div>
```